# Incorrect Login in Codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

I am trying to find the answer to this question: why I appear in the login form in CodeIgniter Incorrect Login Version 3.03.

[image]

I Use: Default Login Username: admin@admin.com Password: password.

[CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth.](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth)

Here is http://pastebin.com/659Ln2yL User extends CI_Controller.
  Log in code http://pastebin.com/Gfh8gPaV. 
  In database a have code from CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth arhive. In autoload is ok

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','form_validation','session','email'); 

$autoload['helper'] = array('html', 'url', 'security', 'form');
```

Answer (score 1):

shoudnt the line

```
 $identity = $this->input->post('email');
```

be

```
 $identity = $this->input->post('identity');
```

@usercontroller line 32